# GNU Prolog assert error

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog, iso-prolog, prolog-assert

I am new to Prolog, but I am stuck at this supposedly simple command. I have loaded
a knowledge base with no errors, and whenever I try do *assert* (and even *help*) I
get the following message:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,assert/1),top_level/0)
{2}
```

What am I exactly missing? Appreciated.

Comment: `assert/1` doesn't exist in GNU Prolog. (That's what "existence_error" means.) You need to use `asserta/1` or `assertz/1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `assertz/1` or `asserta/1` instead. GNU-Prolog does not provide `assert/1` because only `asserta/1` and `assertz/1` are defined in the standard.

Note that while `asserta/1` always had one clear interpretation meaning *add the clause at the beginning*, the meaning of `assertz/1` was more difficult to resolve since "add a clause at the end" does not completely determine the semantics of goals that have been invoked prior to asserting the clause.

With ISO-Prolog, goals that have been invoked prior to `assertz/1` (but also `retract/1`) remain unaffected. This is known as the *logical update view*. To quote the standard (ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995):

> **7.5.4 A logical database update**
>
> Any change in the database that occurs as the result of
>   executing a goal (for example, when the activator of a
>   subgoal is a call of `assertz/1` or `retract/1`) shall affect
>   only an activation whose execution begins afterwards. The
>   change shall not affect any activation that is currently
>   being executed.
>
> NOTE — Thus the database is frozen during the execution of
>   a goal, and the list of clauses defining a predication is fixed at
>   the moment of its execution (see 7.7.7 e).

Note that in DECsystem 10 Prolog, the manual made a big difference between `assert/1` and `assertz/1`. In the following quote from the DECsystem 10 User guide of 1978, the term **implementation defined** can only mean what is known in the standard as **implementation dependent** (meaning essentially undefined).

> **5.5  Meta-Logical**
>
> ...
>
> `assert(C)`
>
> > The current instance of `C` is interpreted as a clause and is added
> >     to  the  current  interpreted program (with new private variables
> >     replacing any uninstantiated variables). The position of the new
> >     clause within the procedure concerned is implementation-defined.
> >     `C` must be instantiated to a non-variable.
>
> `asserta(C)`
>
> > Like `assert(C)`, except that the new clause  becomes  the  first
> >     clause for the procedure concerned.
>
> `assertz(C)`
>
> > Like `assert(C)`, except that the new  clause  becomes  the  last
> >     clause for the procedure concerned.

Also today there are systems where `assert/1` and `assertz/1` differ. E.g., [xsb](/questions/tagged/xsb).

Comment: In XSB assertz/1 gives a warning for a trie, and assert/1 doesn't (Section 6.14). Further strangeness there is some mention in the doc that the logical view is not used and that asserta/1 can be faster than assertz/1.