# Alternative to findall

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I'm trying to create an alternative to `findall` in Prolog.

What I have is:

```
solutions(A,T,S) :- 
   T,
   assert(temp(A)),
   fail.
solutions(A,T,S) :-
   obtain([],S).

obtain(X,S) :-
   retract(temp(A)),
   obtain([A|X],S).
obtain(S,S).
```

This is however giving me inconsistent results. What is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you describe what is *inconsistent* in your results?

Comment: Perhaps using `assertz` instead of `assert` will solve this mysterious inconsistency.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I believe `assert` and `assertz` do the same thing. :)

Comment: @lurker Will assert guarantee appending to the end? I can't find anything mentioning it..

Comment: @EugeneSh. If it's SWI Prolog, then I *believe* it does since [`assert/1` is deprecated in favor of `assertz/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1). I don't know why it would not be consistent. I'm still waiting for the OP to explain what is inconsistent. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your implementation.

1. There is no cleanup in the beginning. Add `retractall(temp(_))` prior to `T,`
2. `obtain/2` will succeed with many different answers, because `retract(temp(A))` will give many answers, and because the second clause `obtain(S,S)` will always be a solution. This can be saved by adding a cut after `retract`.

   ```
   ?- obtain([],S).
      S = [2,1]
   ;  S = [1]
   ;  S = [2]
   ;  S = []
   ;  false.
   ```
3. You may want to change the order, either by using `asserta/1` or by redefining `obtain/2`.
4. Your definition is not re-entrant. That cannot be solved easily. You would need either some `gensym` like functionality or some even more advanced features.
5. For the fine print of `assert/1` vs. `assertz/1` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20027252/772868).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, us a cut (!) after retract/1 and explicitly assertz/1:

```
solutions(A,T,_) :- 
   T,
   assertz(temp(A)),
   fail.
solutions(_,_,S) :-
   obtain(S).

obtain([A|S]) :-
   retract(temp(A)), !,
   obtain(S).
obtain([]).
```

Works fine, but is not reentrant, the second query result is wrong:

```
?- solutions(X,between(1,3,X),L).
L = [1, 2, 3].

?- solutions(X-R,(between(1,3,X),solutions(Y,between(1,X,Y),R)),L).
L = [3-[2-[1-[1], 1, 2], 1, 2, 3]].
```

**Edit 08.11.2020:**
Here is a reentrant solution using gensym/2:

```
solutions(A,T,L) :-
   setup_call_cleanup(
      gensym('bag',B),
      solutions(B,A,T,L),
      retractall(temp(B,_))).

solutions(B,A,T,_) :- 
   T,
   assertz(temp(B,A)),
   fail.
solutions(B,_,_,S) :-
   obtain(B,S).

obtain(B,[A|S]) :-
   retract(temp(B,A)), !,
   obtain(B,S).
obtain(_,[]).
```

Now both queries work fine:

```
?- solutions(X,between(1,3,X),L).
L = [1, 2, 3].

?- solutions(X-R,(between(1,3,X),solutions(Y,between(1,X,Y),R)),L).
L = [1-[1], 2-[1, 2], 3-[1, 2, 3]].
```

**Warning:** A Prolog system with logical update semantics
might be unefficient during repeatedly retract/1.