# gprolog error for default functions: error(existence_error...

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I keep running into an existence error for many different default functions in prolog (I'm using gprolog). For example...

```
| ?- assert(a(1)).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,assert/1),top_level/0)
| ?- g_assign(GVarName, 0).
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,g_assign/2)
| ?- b_setval(A, 0).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,b_setval/2),top_level/0)
```

Do I need to install something else?

Essentially, I'm trying to find a way to define a global variable. I thought something like this might be the best way...

```
fact(List).

predicate(List) :- 
    ...some code...,
    assert(fact(List)).
```

and then to invoke the "global variable" I would use `fact(List)`.

Comment: Read the GNU Prolog manual. GNU Prolog has `asserta/1` and `assertz/1`. You can define `assert(X) :- assertz(X).` if you wish.

Comment: very good thank you!

Comment: any idea why `g_assign ` doesn't exist?

Comment: That's a different error, `instantiation_error`, which means it expects at least one of the variables you provided to be instantiated, but it was not. See http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog045.html.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20027252/772868) for `assert`.